# Iterar sobre el selector actual con XPath y Scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

Estoy escrapeando una información pero estoy atorado en el bucle del for.
Primero, cuando recibo la respuesta, le creo un xpath "root" por así llamarlo. Este xpath root tiene uno y cada uno de los items en un tag `ul` Después saco cada uno de los datos que necesito, pero del xpath root. Este es el código

```
import Scrapy

class SecccionAmarillaSpider( scrapy.spider ):
 name="seccion_amarilla"
 start_urls = ['https://www.seccionamarilla.com.mx/resultados/hospitales/1']
 data = {}

  def parse( self, result ):
    selectors = result.xpath('//ul[@class="list"]/li')
    for selector in selectors:
     name = selector.xpath('//span[itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
     phone = selector.xpath('//span[itemprop="telephone"]/text()').extract()
     #These data is stored in MySQL
```

Anexo imágen de comprensión
[image: Example]
Esta es mi lógica. En el bucle for pasa una variable que se llama `selector` el cual es el índice actual de la lista, por ende de este y solo de este selector puedo sacar la información que necesito, como `name y phone`, Es decir, espero que las variables se llenen así para que pueda construir un SQL

```
name = 'Z'
phone = '( 81)8333 4662'
sql = "INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES('"+name+"','"+phone+"')"
```

En su lugar estoy recibiendo toda la información en un arreglo, como si no estuviera respetando el selector actual y escrapeara de nuevo toda la página, esto es lo que estoy obteniendo

```
name = ['Z','Z-GAS']
phone = ['( 81)8333 4662', '(33)3668 3800']
```

¿Por qué?

No puedo hacer una correlación entre arreglos, también lo pensé, ciclar name y hacer coincider los índices de name y phone, sin embargo la información es muy variable, puede tener o no name o phone, entonces ya no cuadraría la relación de la información.

Alguna sugerencia?
Uso python 3.x y Scrapy 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En estos casos de que quieras recorrer un selector deberías recordar que para que sea relativo no puedes empezar por /, tendrás que empezar por un punto.

Debería funcionar si cambias tu código por:

```
selectors = result.xpath('//ul[@class="list"]/li')
for selector in selectors:
  name = selector.xpath('.//span[itemprop="name"]/text()').extract()
  phone = selector.xpath('.//span[itemprop="telephone"]/text()').extract()
```